# Typescript mixin function inferring from subclass generic type

Tags: typescript, generics, mixins

The following is an example of the problem I am experiencing at the moment.  I'm trying to write a mixin that properly infers and reflects the generic type from the subclass of the class provided to the mixin.

```
abstract class A<T = {}> {
  public abstract init(): T;
}

interface IB {
  something: string;
}

class B extends A<IB> {
  public init(): IB {
    return null;
  }
}

type ConstructorOf<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function ApplyC<T extends ConstructorOf<A>>(base: T) {
  abstract class C extends base {

  }
  return C;
}

class D extends ApplyC(B) {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // this.init()
  }
}
```

Where I written `this.init()`, the intellisense is telling me that I have an overload on `init()`, one is `init(): {}` and the other is `init(): IB`, the problem with this is that I don't want there to appear to be an overload, and I just want the IB one to appear.

I need the `T` in `A<T = {}>` to be inferred somehow in the mixin and pass it to `ConstructorOf<A>` from the `base: T` provided.

Comment: Looks like a bug, and I couldn't find an existing report.  Do you want to [submit a report](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) or shall I?

Comment: Thanks @MattMcCutchen, have submitted bug here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27420

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass generic parameter in Typescript Mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69420801/pass-generic-parameter-in-typescript-mixin)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to restrict the `ApplyC` function to receive only subclasses of `A`?
If no you could replace `A` with `any`, e.g.:

```
    function ApplyC<T extends ConstructorOf<any>>(base: T) {
```

then `D.init()` will return just `IB` and nothing else.