# Pass generic parameter in Typescript Mixin

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mixins

When using a mixin that builds up on a generic class, I need to set it's value to unknown, causing the implementing class having a generic parameter of type `unknown | concrete`.

I've build an example here using Angular, but it's completely Typescript related: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svw6ke?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Is there any chance to redesign this mixin (using Typescript 4.4) so the type won't get malformed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to carry the generic parameter through the mixin function.  [Titian's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48492205/26286) gives a good explanation of how this works.  For your problem, it would look something like

```
export function genericMixin1<
  ModelType,
  ComponentType extends AbstractConstructor<ComponentBase<ModelType>>
>(Base: T) {
  abstract class GenericMixin extends Base {
    //Logic here
  }
  return GenericMixin;
}
```

It helps to know going in that what he calls the "two call approach" stems from a workaround for a common problem with TypeScript generics -- you can't partially infer generic type parameters when calling a function, but you can sort of "divide" the generic parameters between the one you're calling and a second inner function.  For example:

```
export function genericMixin2<T>() {
  return function<
    ComponentType extends AbstractConstructor<ComponentBase<T>>
  >(Base: ComponentType) {
    abstract class GenericMixin extends Base {
      //Logic here
    }
    return GenericMixin;
  };
}
```

(ETA: Fixed, [Playground example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwgewLYAdsA7AUyIgCE0SAeAFQD4EBvBAXwFgAobiAT3wkEAQXDQ4EHEUhQArvGxR6TALwJQMiQlIB3ABQA6I8CgBzMAC51RPgG0AugEoEKpnQDc3biQAehKIgAZrJE8ACWxAimZCRQYbAAsmE+YUQATMp6zszcCAhQJBCyUEQIwaEQEUQ0OATEZBB0AkK+EGQAJhiimvBSMvIQijV4hKTkVGC0jAwMehMkVrWjDU2C2bl56mIw8Eio6AgA4jFxicmpCK0dGPMsG5sIAPSPADLYpvEIABaxJPfs-wKRRKRxO8SSKSIni4eTY0M4XCAA).)

Now instead of writing `const StringMixin = genericMixin1<string, ComponentBase<string>>(ComponentBase);` you can write `const StringMixin = (genericMixin2<string>()(ComponentBase))`.  This is only a slight improvement with one generic parameter, but becomes absolutely necessary when you have many generic params. Otherwise, you wind up with `const ManyParamsMixin = genericMixin<string, number, boolean, BaseThing<string,number,boolean>>(BaseThing)`... it gets ugly fast.

Comment: Something seams to be wrong with your syntax here. I can't use the code

`export function genericMixin2<T>() {
  return function<ComponentBase<T>>(Base: T) {
    abstract class GenericMixin extends Base {
      //Logic here
    }
    return GenericMixin;
  };
}`

TS doesn't seam to like "return function < ..."

Comment: Thanks, I made an error transcribing the generic parameter definition for the nested function.  It should work now.

Comment: Thank you very much, but still something seams to be wrong / I don't get it. Error occurs as soon as I use my mixin: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwgewLYAdsA7AUyIgCE0SAeAFQD4EBvBAXwFgAobiAT3wkEAQXDQ4EHEUhQArvGxR6TALwJQMiQlIB3ABQA6I8CgBzMAC51RPgG0AugEoEKpnQDc3biQAehKIgAZrJE8ACWxAimZCRQYbAAsmE+YUQATMp6zszcCAhQJBCyUEQIwaEQEUQ0OATEZBB0AkK+EGQAJhiimvBSMvIQijV4hKTkVGC0jAwMehMkVrWjDU2C2bl56mIw8Eio6AgA4jFxicmpCK0dGPMsG5sIAPSPADLYpvEIABaxJPfs-wKRRKRxO8SSKSIni4eTY0M4PC4sGIkAQAGVoKlTBCLmo9NFSKccekaDIsbNHHolvVxtRHI4vFxfP5ECg0BgMXEiKZqWNEFciJ10ZjucSWOwgA

Comment: [The returned mixin is still generic.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false&ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=13&pc=2#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwgewLYAdsA7AUyIgCE0SAeAFQD4EBvAWACgEFRIZ4EAZtmwAuBHQDcHAL4cOEAJ74SCAILhocCDiK8ArvGxR6TALzcNfRKQDuACgB0T4FADmYMcCIKA2gF0ASgRTJkk5dhIAD0IoRAE9IngAS2IEVzISKCTYAFkkyKSiACYTOyC2TgQoEgg9KCJBBOTiGhwCYjIIOiUVKIgyABMMdV4tHX1DYzbCUnIqMFpGBgY7eZIxaY7ybuVyji4uHk1+FDQMAHEMrNz8woQ+wYw1ln2DrhAXYIQAFiKpSq4sgBVRqdQal1I1zyBSI-0B-yBHFgxEgCAAytBCq5oXdzHZ0pDsjjijReFiVgE7JtZpRqAEAuEojFEKd0OjMURXNTOvdIv0iEN2VlOcTSRzXEwKlwhNgvgAiAAWJGQyGwcoRQA)

Comment: Super cool, thank you so much! Never thought this issue will ever get resolved!

Comment: It's getting even more complicated. Now I want to have a _DefaultGenericBaseClass_, already having this mixin included (link in next comment). Guess we're leaving the possibilities here? :/

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwgewLYAdsA7AUyIgCE0SAeAFQD4EBvAWACgEFRIZ4EAZtmwAuBHQDcHAL4cOEAJ74SCAILhocCDiK8ArvGxR6TALzcNfRKQDuACgB0T4FADmYMcCIKA2gF0ASgRTJkk5dhIAD0IoRAE9IngAS2IEVzISKCTYAFkkyKSiACYTOyC2TgQoEgg9KCJBBOTiGhwCYjIIOiUVKIgyABMMdV4tHX1DYzbCUnIqMFpGBgY7eZIxaY7ybuVyji4uHk1+FDQMAHEMrNz8woQ+wYw1ln2DrhAXYIQAFiKpSq4sgBVRqdQal1I1zyBSI-0B-yBHFgxEgCAAytBCq5oXdzHZ0pDsjjijReFiVgE7JtZpRqAEAuEojFEKd0OjMURXNTOvdIv0iEN2VlOcTSRzXEwKlwhNgvgAiAAWJGQyGwcoRjOiRkQRysSFQbIhmWya0wBrAJl5-MFBONNxhJUYZSpeBmnTWARMUoQMiAA

Comment: I think you can solve your problem with more wrapper functions, or more generic arguments to your existing wrapper function.  You can't pass a class-generic value to the `extends` class (as your example shows) but you can return a generated class from a mixin function that uses that function's generic parameter as a base-class generic type value.

Comment: Could you be so kind and adopt my example? I just can't imagine what you mean, I'm sorry.

Comment: It might help to put some actual example logic in your various classes.  I *think* this is what you want: `export function genericBaseMixin<T>() {
  abstract class GenericBaseClass extends genericMixin2<T>()(ComponentBase)<T>{
  }
  return GenericBaseClass;
}`.  (Paste into your example, replacing the lines after 22.)  It's hard to share in comments, maybe if you still have issues you can try asking for further help on the Typescript channel on Gitter.im -- they're usually very good.

Comment: Ah, I see! The idea is to have a base function creating my class instead of a base class! Sure that's the solution!

Answer (score 2):

## Update: simpler solution

You can forgo the `extends` clause in your mixin function and just use a generic `T` to represent your `BehaviorSubject` type:

```js
export abstract class ComponentBase<T> {
  model$ = new BehaviorSubject<T>(null);
}

export function genericMixin<T>(Base: AbstractConstructor<ComponentBase<T>>) {
  abstract class GenericMixin extends Base {
    //Logic here
  }
  return GenericMixin;
}
```

This works without having to do any casting. Your `AppComponent` class will also extend a little differently:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent extends genericMixin<Model>(ComponentBase) {
  name = 'Angular';

  method(): void {
    this.model$.subscribe((v) => console.log(v.value));
  }
}
```

But your `model$` property should still infer correctly. Let me know if that works!

## First solution

You can extract the type of your `AbstractConstructor` base class argument and explicitly annotate your return type from the mixin function, like so:

```js
// An interface that represents what you're mixing in
interface WithModel<T> {
  model$: BehaviorSubject<T>;
}

// Extracting the type of your `AbstractConstructor` parameter
type ExtractModelType<T extends AbstractConstructor<ComponentBase<any>>> =
  T extends AbstractConstructor<ComponentBase<infer U>> ? U : never;

// Then in your mixin function
export function genericMixin<
  T extends AbstractConstructor<ComponentBase<unknown>>
>(Base: T): T & WithModel<ExtractModelType<T>> {
  abstract class GenericMixin extends Base {
    // Logic here
  }
  return GenericMixin as T & WithModel<ExtractModelType<T>>;
}
```

Now accessing the `model$` parameter from derived classes should yield the correct type.

```js
class Model {
  value: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent extends genericMixin(ComponentBase)<Model> {
  name = 'Angular';

  method(): void {
    // `model$` is correctly inferred as a `Model` here.
    this.model$.subscribe((v) => console.log(v.value));
  }
}
```

Comment: The first solution works perfect, thank you! The _simplified_ one doesn't seam to work. Can you maybe modify the Stackblitz regardingly?

Comment: Oh no. The first solution stopped working too, as soon as you put **any** logic in it. Replace `//Logic here` even with `s: string;` and the build fails.

Check out here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r43l8c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts.

Comment: Hmm.. you're right about the first solution failing as soon as you add additional properties. I couldn't find a way around that without extensive type casting. Check out a working implementation of the simpler solution [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqm4kf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Too bad this leads to two new issues (marked as #1 & #2): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knt396?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

#1: I cannot prepare generic mixin combinations anymore since the type need to be set the time it is declared.
#2: The type-information is lost and mixins cannot be combined any more.

But: its getting closer!

Comment: Check out [this example](https://angular-13gkwr.stackblitz.io). Seems to be working for multiple mixins. The implementations of your `genericMixin2` function and `ComponentDefault` have changed a bit. Let me know if that works!

Comment: Your stackblitz somehow never loads for me. Can you give it a try? First I thought their servers have problems, but others work.

Comment: Oops, pasted the wrong link. Here's the [editor link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13gkwr?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Puh ... ok, guess that could do it. My example was actually strongly simplified, so I need to check how to adopt this to my use-case. But I'll mark it as answered until I find an issue with it :)

Comment: Using your solution I somehow can't combine multiple mixins (next comment):

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false#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

Comment: (Needed to shorten it because of comment lenght)